# Unity app not responding and get "request time out" when call to WebAPI

Tags: api, unity-game-engine, timeout

I'm having a Unity app call to a Like() method in DLL, which connect to a WebAPI to do the job. However, when I debug the application and code run to

```
string liked = SocialConnector.LikePost(token, postID);
```

It got stuck there, unity became not responding and after work normal again, the debug show Request time out.

Below are my detail code in DLL

```
public static String LikePost(String token, String postID)
    {
        HttpCommon common = new HttpCommon();
        string url = Constant.ApiURL + Constant.API_LINK_POST_LIKE_UNLIKE + "?postID=" + postID;
        String result = common.HttpPost<String>(url, token);
        return result;
    }
```

Code in HTTPCommon

```
public T HttpPost<T>(String url, String token)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        //var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        //request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
        var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        try
        {                
            var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
            return responseData;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(responseString);
        }
    }
```

Error log:

```
WebException: The request timed out
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse ()
GSEP_DLL.Connectors.HttpCommon.HttpPost[String] (System.String url,      System.String token)
GSEP_DLL.Connectors.SocialConnector.LikePost (System.String token,   System.String postID)
Like.onClick () (at Assets/Scripts/Like.cs:39)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke (System.Object[] args) (at    C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:110)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at    C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:574)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:716)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_0.cs:53)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:35)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick    (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at  C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:44)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler     handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:52)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler]   (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:269)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

**Update**: Problem solved. The WebAPI return type of bool but my DLL forced to return String.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The WebAPI return type of bool but my DLL forced to return String.